# Creating collapsible rows in NSTableview using swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

In ios we have expandable rows for UITableview, which on clicking shows subrows.

I would like a similar implementation in mac osx application in nstableview using swift.

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Why don't you use NSOutlineView?

Comment: @Carpsen90 I tried inserting subrows using tableView delegate method insertRows(at: <#T##IndexSet#>, withAnimation: <#T##NSTableViewAnimationOptions#>) but it is creating a new row duplicating the values of row number passed as indexset. I need to toggle(hide/show) sub rows on click of any row in nstableview.

Comment: @ElTomato for now need to do it in nstableview. So not tried NSoutlineView.

Comment: @sourav inserting rows is an improvisation that is going to mess with the model and make the code less clear. the Apple way of dealing with expanding cells is to change the height of the cell to reveal/hide the rest of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You may add an IBAction to the button that expands the cell, and adjust the height auto layout constraint of the cell:

```
//Set an IBOutlet to the cell's height constraint
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func expandCellAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    heightConstraint.constant = someValue
    yourView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Or if you wish to expand the cell when it's selected use this function

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    heightConstraint.constant = someValue
    yourView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/InfoBarStackView/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app from Apple.

Comment: Thank u.. will try this.